# Python WS Server and Java WS Client

Tags: java, python, web-services, soa

I have implemented a simple Web Services Server with [`pyws`](http://stepank.github.io/pyws/1.1.2/introduction.html) and [`suds`](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation).

```
from pyws.server import SoapServer 
from pyws.functions.register import register

server = SoapServer(
        service_name = 'Test',
        tns = 'http://example.com',
        location = 'http://localhost:8000/soa/', 
)

@register() 
def add_simple(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This is how I can access it in the python shell:

```
>>> import suds
>>> client = suds.client.Client('http://localhost:8000/soa/wsdl', cache=None)
>>> client.service.add_simple('hello ', 'world')
hello world
```

Accessing `http://localhost:8000/soa` will produce this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>None</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <name>XMLSyntaxError</name>
        <prefix>lxml.etree</prefix>
        <exceptionName>comtypes.example.Error</exceptionName>
        <params>
          <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </params>
        <message>None</message>
        <type>Client</type>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And `http://localhost:8000/soa/wsdl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:types="http://example.comtypes/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://example.com" name="Test">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.comtypes/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://example.comtypes/">
      <xsd:element name="add_simple">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="a" nillable="true"/>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="b" nillable="true"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="add_simple_result">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="result" nillable="true"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="Error">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://example.comtypes/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="error">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="types:Error"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="add_simple">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="types:add_simple"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="add_simple_result">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="types:add_simple_result"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="TestPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="add_simple">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:add_simple"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:add_simple_result"/>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:error" name="error"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding type="tns:TestPortType" name="TestBinding">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="add_simple">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.comadd_simple"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="error">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="error"/>
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="TestService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:TestBinding" name="TestPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/soa/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

How can I access this service form a java (for the sake of simplicity) console app?
I'm asking this beacause usually, in a java client you would create an instance of the class that you are trying to use, and that is not applicable in this case.
I need to mention that I have tested this web service using the eclipse web service browser and it worked - I just don't know how to integrate it in a java program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create at least one class with a main method.
So after compilation, you can use a command like :

> java className localhost:8000/soa/wsdl hello world

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String host = args[0];
    String hello = args[1];
    String world = args[2];

    System.out.println(hello+" "+world);

}
```

Comment: This does not access the web service, it just implements the method.